# Remove a character from a transformed String which may come or may not come in a String

Tags: java

I am trying to modify a String in such a way that it does not display the square braces as well as the character ',' in it. The comma character actually may or may not be displayed in the String but I am not able to remove that.

```
public static String removeSquareBracesFromStringForPgNumberValidation(String string) {
        
        StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder(string);
        str.deleteCharAt(0);
        str.deleteCharAt(string.length() - 2);
        try {
            str.toString().replace(",", "");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return str.toString();
```

This is the code I am trying and if I pass "[5,055]" as an argument to this method, the output given is 5,055. The square braces are removed but the comma stays as it is. My expected output is 5055. The comma code I have added in try catch as it may or may not be displayed in the String which I pass as the argument. Please help me to achieve desired output.

Comment: Strings are immutable meaning once created they cannot be changed/modified. Any method you call on a String that modifies the String will therefor always return the modified String. `.replace(",", "");` Will return you the new String with the replacement, but neither modify the String the method was called on nor have any effect on your Stringbuilder. Just use `string = string.replace(",", "").` as the first cal in your method to do the desired modification and correctly save the returned new string in the variable

Comment: `return string.replace(",", "").replace("[", "").replace("]", "");`

Comment: Or with a regex: `return string.replaceAll("\\[|\\]|,", "");`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`str.toString()` returns the current string content.
With `str.toString().replace(",", "")` you create a new `String` (`String` is final) without comma but you don't use this value.
So you can directly `return str.toString().replace(",", "");`

Answer (score 0):

The [Answer by Warminski](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72461708/642706) is correct.

Another approach is to filter a stream of the [code point](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_point) integer numbers that represent each character in the input string.

We want to filter out 44 for COMMA, 91 for LEFT SQUARE BRACKET, and 93 for RIGHT SQUARE BRACKET.

```
final int LEFT = "[".codePointAt( 0 ) ;  // 91.
final int COMMA = ",".codePointAt( 0 ) ;  // 44.
final int RIGHT = "]".codePointAt( 0 ) ;  // 93.
String result = 
    "[5,055]"
    .codePoints()
    .filter( codePoint -> ! ( ( codePoint == LEFT ) || ( codePoint == COMMA ) || ( codePoint == RIGHT ) ) )
    .collect( StringBuilder::new , StringBuilder::appendCodePoint , StringBuilder::append )
    .toString() 
;
```

See this [code run live at IdeOne.com](https://ideone.com/sNk58a).

> 5055